# Is uart close/open is mandatory before every att configuration?

Tags: c, linux, uart

A uart application coding demo in linux is as following,

```
    typedef struct devpara {
      int fd;
      int num;
    } devpara_t;
   
    devpara_t *dpara = malloc(sizeof(devpara_t));
    
    dpara->hd = openuart("/ttyS0");  // here, (O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    if (dpara->hd < 0)
        return -1;
    configuart(dpara->hd, 115200, 8, 1, NOPAR, 1 /* stopbits */);

    //do some job here, then need change baudrate to 9600,
```

if I need do uart close and open before reconfiguration, like this, let's call it case one,

```
    closeuart(dpara->hd);
    dpara->hd = openuart("/ttyS0");
    if (dpara->hd < 0)
        return -1;
    configuart(dpara->hd, 9600, 8, 1, NOPAR, 1 /* stopbits */);
```

or just need reconfigure new parameters directly, as following. Let's call it case two,

```
    configuart(dpara->hd, 9600, 8, 1, NOPAR, 1 /* stopbits */);
```

Comment: There should be no reason to close the UART before reconfiguring. You can control when the reconfiguration occurs with `tcsetattr()`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks. I tried two host uart tools recently, which required user to close and reopen port before changing some parameters, so I had thought there should be some dependency inside.

Comment: It depends on required modem control lines behavior.